# android - make content provider available to one package only

Tags: android, package, android-contentprovider

is there any way to make an external content provider available to only one package?
for example available only to my app?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Although its too late, I would like to share the answer which I have found,
You need to declare your own custom permission inside manifest file of content provider application like this..

`<permission android:name= "com.android.testpermission"  android:protectionLevel="signature" >`

And inside your Content Provider  tag you have to specify a permission that a client is required to have like this way...

`<provider android:name=".MyProvider"
android:authorities="com.example.contentproviderexample.MyProvider" android:exported="true"            android:permission="com.android.testpermission"        android:multiprocess="true" ></provider>`

And inside your 2nd application to access content provider data you need to specify the uses permission inside manifest file,like this..

`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.testpermission"/>`
Now sign both the application using same keystore signature & this way any other application can't access your content provider data. Only applications that hold those permissions & signed with same keystore signature will be able to access the provider data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add permissions to the manifest declaration for the content provider. Only applications that hold those permissions will be able to access the provider.

Comment: yes i knew that, but that way the provider is always accessible from who knows the permission string

Comment: Yes, the only other way would be to restrict the content provider to your application by making it private (ie: setting `android:exported="false"`). However this will only work if the content provider is a part of your application.

Comment: My achievement is allow users download and use themes in my app but i'd like to let users or third part create their own themes and publish them on google play.